# How can I Bold one Word in a Line in iText 7?

Tags: itext7, typography

I can set text bold using iText 7 like so:

```
parExecSummHeader2.Add(new Text(subj).SetBold());
```

...but when I try to combine a "normal" (non-bolded) bit of text with a bolded part, it doesn't work. I have this, which prints the line all "regular" (no bold):

```
parExecSummHeader2.Add("Average words per sentence (the general average is 15 - 20): " + Math.Round(WordsPerSentenceInDoc, 2).ToString());
```

...but want to make the calculated value bold. I tried both this:

```
parExecSummHeader2.Add("Average words per sentence (the general average is 15 - 20): ");
parExecSummHeader2.Add(new Text(Math.Round(WordsPerSentenceInDoc, 2).ToString().SetBold()));
```

...and this:

```
parExecSummHeader2.Add("Average words per sentence (the general average is 15 - 20): ");
string mathval = Math.Round(WordsPerSentenceInDoc, 2).ToString();
parExecSummHeader2.Add(new Text(mathval.SetBold()));
```

...but they both won't compile, complaining, "Error CS1061  'string' does not contain a definition for 'SetBold' and no accessible extension method 'SetBold' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found"

Comment: Thanks for the bounty! You absolutely didn't have to, but it's very pleasant still :)

Comment: @AlexeySubach: No worries; I like to be generous with bountifying, partly so that I will get a reputation for such and people will be more willing to answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shorter option which may result in not perfect quality of text rendering because bold simulation is used instead of a proper bold font:

```
Paragraph parExecSummHeader2 = new Paragraph();
parExecSummHeader2.Add("Average words per sentence (the general average is 15 - 20): ");
parExecSummHeader2.Add(new Text("123").SetBold());
```

Option with more code but better output quality because the proper bold font is use:

```
PdfFont boldFont = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD);
Paragraph parExecSummHeader2 = new Paragraph();
parExecSummHeader2.Add("Average words per sentence (the general average is 15 - 20): ");
parExecSummHeader2.Add(new Text("123").SetFont(boldFont));
```

Answer (score 1):

For iText 7:

```
public static final Font HELVETICA_BOLD =
new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLUE);

new Text("MyText").setFontColor(Color.BLUE)
.setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA_BOLD));
```

You have some more details examples [here](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-make-a-single-letter-bold-within-a-word)

For iText 5:

```
 public const string DEFAULT_FONT_FAMILY = "Arial";

 public static Font SmallFontBold
    {
        get
        {
            BaseColor black = new BaseColor(0, 0, 0);
            Font font = FontFactory.GetFont(DEFAULT_FONT_FAMILY, 10, Font.BOLD, black);
            return font;
        }//get
    }//SmallFontBold

...   

Phrase aPh = new Phrase("My Bold", SmallFontBold);
```

And from here, you can try to use it combined.

Comment: BaseColor is not recognized.